# WMS request issue(File size increasing on its own)

Tags: geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff

This is my code for reference,

tif_getter.py,

```
from fastapi import Request, Response, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from app.db import file_db
import requests


GEOSERVER_URL = "http://192.168.1.158:8080/geoserver/wms"
srs = ""
height = ""
width = ""
bbox = ""
    

# @app.get("/geoserver/wms")
async def get_map_request(
        layers: str,
        # request: Request,
        request: str = "GetMap",
        service: str = "WMS",
        version: str = "1.1.1",
        # format: str = "application/openlayers",
        format: str = "image/geotiff"
):
    layer_detail ={} 
    tif_details = None
    for filename in file_db:
        if filename.get('file_name') == layers:
            tif_details = filename
    
    if not tif_details:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Layer not found!")
    
    srs = tif_details["srs"]
    height = tif_details["height"]
    width = tif_details["width"]
    bbox = tif_details["bbox"]
    bbox_str = f"{bbox[0]},{bbox[1]},{bbox[2]},{bbox[3]}"

    if layers.endswith(".tif"):
        layers = layers[:-4]  # Remove the last 4 characters (".tif")
    

    # You can perform additional validation or processing as needed

    # Construct the GeoServer WMS request URL
    wms_request = (
        f"{GEOSERVER_URL}?"
        f"request={request}&"
        f"service={service}&"
        f"version={version}&"
        f"layers={layers}&"
        f"styles=&"
        f"srs={srs}&"
        f"bbox={bbox_str}&"
        f"width={width}&"
        f"height={height}&"
        f"format={format}"
    )


    # response = requests.get(wms_request)
    # return wms_request


    # response = requests.get(wms_request)
    response = requests.get(wms_request, stream=True)


    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("WMS request successful")
        # data = response.content
        # return Response(content=data, media_type="image/geotiff")
        # return Response(content=data, media_type="application/xml")
        return StreamingResponse(response.iter_content(chunk_size=2048), media_type="image/geotiff")
        # return StreamingResponse(response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), media_type="application/openlayers")
        # return StreamingResponse(response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024), media_type="application/xml")

        
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")
```

Now i have the functionality where if a tif file is uploaded into a folder, it gets made into a geotiff layer in geoserver. Now that is working all fine.

The above is my code to try and retrieve that layer through a wms request.

Here i am running into an issue where the tif life that was made into a layer was only 54.6 mb. But the geotiff image im receiving from the wms request is 944 mb.
I have no clue why it is happening.
My end requirement is that i be able to display a particular layer on a map.

Are there are any modifications i could make or is there is a better way to handle the same?

Comment: I bet that your input image is compressed and your output image is uncompressed. I do not know it it is possible to configure the WMS output of GeoServer to create compressed tiffs. WCS supports at least deflate compression https://docs.geoserver.org/2.21.x/en/user/services/wcs/webadmin.html.

Comment: Also WMS is returning a picture of your image not the image itself

Comment: would wcs or wms be a better option to retrieve my geotiff coveragee store?

Comment: Also is there anyway to know if my input tif image is compressed or not?